# How to plot multiple line graphs from a CSV dataframe

Tags: python, pandas, numpy, matplotlib

I'm new to using Pandas/Numpy/Matplotlib etc, but wish to sort this out:

I currently have this CSV file: https://drive.google.com/file/d/1bRhbKaYi3lIz88iZPDIgMBq3q7nWoe7_/view?usp=sharing

I wish to make line graphs for all 30 products listed in the dataframe, how can I do so?

What I have tried so far (pretty much a complete failure):

```
import matplotlib as mpl
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import seaborn as sns
import numpy as np
import pandas as pd  
plt.rcParams.update({'figure.figsize': (10,7), 'figure.dpi': 120})

df = pd.read_csv(testdata.csv)

def plot_df(df,title="", xlabel='Date', ylabel='Value', dpi=100):
    plt.figure(figsize=(16,5), dpi=dpi)
    plt.plot(color='tab:red')
    plt.gca().set(title=title, xlabel=xlabel, ylabel=ylabel)
    plt.show()


plot_df(df,  title='Test Graph.')
```

Ideally the desired outcome is for all 30 product's line graphs to be plotted with the same timeframe axis.

If there's a better way to represent the data, do let me know!

Answer (score 0):

firstly we have to import libraries

```
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import seaborn as sns
```

now we are converting string type to datetime by passing 'Date' column to `parse_dates` parameter of `read_csv() method`

`df = pd.read_csv('testdata.csv',parse_dates=['Date'])`

now we are storing columns value of `df` in col from Product1 to Product30

`col=df.columns[1:]`

now we are creating a `Yearly Date Range` from march 2007 to march 2019 as there are 145 date values so we can't see x lable because there are plenty of dates

`date=pd.date_range(df.loc[0,'Date'],df.loc[144,'Date'],freq='Y')`

now lets start plotting data

```
plt.figure(figsize=(24,14),dpi=120)
legends=[]
for x in col:
    legends.append(x)
    plt.plot(df['Date'],df[x])
    plt.legend(legends,loc='upper right',fontsize=8)
plt.xlabel('Years',fontsize=13.5,fontweight='bold')
plt.ylabel('Values',fontsize=13.5,fontweight='bold')
plt.title('Test graph',fontsize=18,fontweight='bold')
plt.xticks(date,rotation=35)
sns.despine()
plt.show()
```